# VB.NET Classes and methods

Tags: vb.net, class

```
Public Class Form1

  Public Sub _A()
    B._B() ' Why i could not do taht
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class B

  Public Sub _B()
    Form1._A() ' Why i could do that
  End Sub
End Class
```

I now that i could just use shared -- Public Shared Sub _B() -- ,,, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Written that way, you couldn't do either...

Comment: `_B()` is an **instance** method - meaning an instance of an object.  You don't have an instance yet.  Same thing with the second line of code - you need an instance of `Form1` to do `Form1._A()`.

Comment: I test Form1._A() it's working fine you dont have to crate instance  of it ?

Comment: @Al.Pertro - that doesn't make any sense.  Based on the code you posted, neither one should work.  Is there more code that you're not showing?

Comment: I now  that doesn't make any sense ,,, thats why i ask ,,, no thats all code

Comment: Is this a console project, WinForm project, or..?

Comment: It's WinForm project.

Comment: @Tim : the Form class is special, a VB6 artifact.  It is allowed to be used as though it is an instance of the class.  This of course completely ruins a VB.NET programmer's mind, making it impossible for him to understand the difference between a type and an object.

Comment: @HansPassant - Ah...I was wondering if it was a VB thing or not, as I was able to reproduce it.  You should post it as answer, as I was really scratching my head on this one (And it wasn't even my question).

Comment: Then it's just written that way , the Q now is : could we use it in our code like this way or there is some side effects ,,, thanks

Comment: @Al.Pertro - I can't think of any particular side effect, outside of confusing other developers who might be maintaining your code and perpetuating the legacy of...questionable...VB programming practices.  On the rare times I have to deal with VB.NET, I try to avoid using anything that is backwards compatible with VB.

Comment: If you add 

Public Class B
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form --- its will work fine ,but thats will make the Class B like form i think

Comment: @Al.Pertro - Why would you do that?  Is `B` a Form?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish or what problem are you trying to solve?  I'd bet dollars to donuts that there is a better way to do it or resolve it then relying to VB hacks.  What happens if MS removes all the backwards compatability for VB from .NET at some point in the future?

Comment: I just was trying to understand what's happening nothing else and now i get it . Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the compiler generated code via a decompiler like Jetbrain's dotPeek you'll find the following code in `B`s `_B` methode:

```
public void _B()
{
  MyProject.Forms.Form1._A();
}
```

The `MyProject` class is automatically generated by the vb.net compiler and allows an easy access to your forms. Inside this Helper class there is a reference to your actual `Form1` object.

As Hans Passant said in the comments this isn't really helpful for a VB.NET programmer to understand the difference so you might better avoid using this.